# creating toy examples for machine learning prototype

Tags: python, image-processing, multidimensional-array, machine-learning

I want to create some simple (approx) 20x20x20 matrices in numpy, essentially of zeors, with a solid 3D shape (ones) located somewhere in the image.

This is so I can test my neural network without running on full size images.

is there a simple way I can do this? Or should I create them by hand?

Thanks

Comment: how should those shapes look like? regular shapes?

Comment: yea, fairly uniform shapes, perhaps elliptical? but localised in one area :) essentially looking like this:http://www.maplesoft.com/view.aspx?SI=4838/PlottingTips_47.gif   all with slight variations.

Comment: than just write a function that creates a sphere with a given radius, or a cube. should be rather easy. with a function you can simply use parameters like size to get different objects quickly. of course if you only need like 3 objects drawing by hand might be quicker.